# What is the difference between "English" and "British"?

Tags: british-english, connotation, ethnonyms

As an American, **I naively think of British and English as exact synonyms**. I know I'm wrong, but I just don't know in what way. I am vaguely aware that people in the UK hold strong opinions about one or the other term and how it is applied, and using one instead of the other has dire social implications.

So there is geography (Britain vs. England), but more importantly the adjectives British and English, and those adjectives each one by themselves, may mean different things in different contexts, and depending on the speaker and the listener.

Can anyone explain the nuances of the differences as used by those who might consider themselves English (or British, if that's an acceptable usage)? How about by the non-English/non-British (again if it's appropriate to use such terms).

(What I am not asking: I had to hold back from asking exactly what the distinctions among UK, British Isles, Great Britain, etc are as well as things like are people from Northern Ireland considered Irish (or do you call them Irish).)

Comment: Sean Connery, Timothy Dalton, and Daniel Craig are all British, but Sean Connery is Scottish, Timothy Dalton is Welsh, and Daniel Craig is English.

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45567/what-is-the-proper-adjective-for-the-uk

Comment: @Mitch: Just to note, using the words "England" or "English" when referring to the UK or British is quite common the world over. To illustrate, people in The Netherlands, France, China, Japan, and Indonesia frequently refer to England when they actually mean the UK. It's not just Americans that tend to treat the two as nearly synonymous!

Comment: @Bjorn: It is indeed common the world over, but that doesn't make it right!

Comment: @Hugo: I quite agree! I do fear it will be a long time yet before the distinction is readily recognized in countries outside the UK though. Most people are also not aware that the Union Jack merges the flags or England, Scotland, and Northern Ireland - and I find it's always great fun, and a good visual aid to boot, to show them how the flags combine when explaining the difference between England and the UK.

Comment: @Bjorn: Ah, but Wales is not represented on the union flag.

Comment: @Hugo: Yes, I always feel bad when having to tag on Wales at the end of my explanation. Who knows, maybe the Union Jack will be updated to include that red dragon at some point in the future so that my visual explanation can be conducted without footnotes.

Comment: @Bjorn, No that would be wrong. You cannot have a dragon on the Union flag - there are no national / heraldic symbols of Scotland or England on it either - the fact that it is on the Welsh flag is irrelevant - and it would disrupt the pattern and geometry of the flag. Adding green would a different matter, and I am all for representing Wales in some way. Just not through a symbol!! =)

Comment: This strikes me as a general reference question - wikipedia or any geographical reference can explain the difference between Britain, the United Kingdom, and England, and their respective demonyms.

Comment: C.G.P. Grey gives a rather good overview of the various terms: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNu8XDBSn10

Comment: It's the [Cross of St David](http://www.seiyaku.com/customs/crosses/david.html) that's missing from the Union Flag (it's currently a composite of the crosses of St George, St Andrew, and St Patrick).

Comment: People are always talking about Britannia major without given Britannia minor its due. Just as there is a Great Britain, so too is there a Lesser Britain: Britanny.

Comment: Is it not the case that Wales is left of the Union Flag because it's a principality and other countries are kingdoms, Ireland having been split after the flag was made?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The country of which I am a citizen is the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland. Great Britain is the largest of the British Isles and is home to England, Scotland and Wales. I was born in England and, apart from several extended periods abroad, have lived my life in England. That makes me ethnically English and politically British.  Although Great Britain is a geographical term, *British* describes nationals of the whole of the United Kingdom and *Britain* is sometimes used to mean the United Kingdom.
Things are often perceived differently abroad, and even by some of the British themselves. The whole political entity is frequently referred to as *England*, even though England is only a part of it. That doesn’t usually bother the English, but it might bother the Welsh, the Scots and the Northern Irish. 
The best policy is to call the country the United Kingdom or, less formally, Britain. Call the people British, unless you know them to be English, Welsh, Scottish or Northern Irish or something else.

**EDIT:**

The title ‘The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland’ raises an interesting linguistic, as well as political, point. Syntactically, it’s ambiguous. Is it ‘(The United Kingdom) of (Great Britain and Northern Ireland’)  or is it ‘(The United Kingdom of Great Britain) and (Northern Ireland)’?

In [‘The Isles: A History’](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195134427), Norman Davies traces the various titles by which the isles have been known. From 1660 to 1707 it was ‘The Kingdom of England and Wales’. The union with Scotland in 1707 gave us ‘The united Kingdom of Great Britain’. Meanwhile, there was a Kingdom of Ireland from 1660 to 1800. In 1801, Ireland was included in ‘The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland’. That state of affairs lasted until 1922 when Ireland divided, allowing the six northern Irish counties to become part of ‘The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland’.

The original ‘united kingdom’ of 1707 was so called because it united England (with Wales) and Scotland. The addition of ‘Ireland’ in 1801 and of ‘Northern Ireland’ in 1922 can therefore be seen as mere accretions to an already united kingdom. However, the grammatical ambiguity allows the alternative interpretation of **all** components of the State being united under a single crown. A good example, perhaps, of Engli-, sorry, British, compromise.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is (mostly) a correspondence between geographical name and preferred ethnic name? **UK = British** (if you don't know otherwise) and **England = English** (not Scotland/Wales/etc)? I vaguely remember from something the phrase '(expletive) Brits' used by ... people associated with the Irish island (sorry it's exactly getting the nomenclature right that is my problem). So they weren't really really complaining about ethnic English but about the political British?

Comment: @Mitch: First part, correct, except there are English living in Wales, Scots living in England, and so on. For extreme Irish nationalists, both north and south of the border, all inhabitants of Great Britain, as well as Protestant Northern Irish, are villains, with the possible exception of Scottish Catholics.

Comment: ...and are all those 'villains' referred to as 'British' or 'Brits'? (those two may not be the same)

Comment: @Mitch: 'Brits' means 'British', but in practice, the target of those who wish to insult those they see as their opponents will be largely English, simply because there are more English than there are Scots or Welsh, and because the English are more readily identifiable as the former colonial power.

Comment: @BarrieEngland There's also a bit of a 'flag of convenience' aspect to use of the term 'Brits' as well. Obviously, people from all over Britain have been involved in the occupation of Ireland over the past centuries, so 'Brits' is obviously accurate here. But when some kind of "Pan-Celtic" unity is being alluded to, Brit can also just mean English.

Comment: The Guardian did a survey on how people identified themselves http://www.guardian.co.uk/news/datablog/2011/oct/17/britishness-map-visualisation-data -- but for some of us it's not black and white. I usually say I'm "between 20% and 80% Welsh, depending on what you count" - parentage, languages spoken, national football teams supported, place of birth, place of upbringing, place of residence, etc.

Comment: @slim: 'Not black and white'. I trust not.

Comment: @BarrieEngland. Most Unionists in Northern Ireland would trace their ancestry back to the plantations, and most of them came originally from Scotland, not England.

Comment: What about the Manx? What are they?

Comment: @tchrist: The Isle of Man is, like each of the Channel Islands, a Crown Dependency.

Comment: In this context, Barrie, 'Brits' sometimes but by no means necessarily means 'British'.

'Brits' always means modern people politically seeing themselves as part of the UK, as opposed to any other English-speaking group, particularly Irish. 

'British' might mean that but sometimes refers to the race or culture of several thousand years ago.

Comment: This is actually very simple.  The United Kingdom comprises England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland.  People from all four of these countries are British.  Scottish, English, Welsh and Northern Irish people are people from each of these four countries.  Hence, a Scottish person is both Scottish and British, but not English.  On a very basic level, there is nothing more complicated to it than that.  This is why Scottish, Welsh and (some) NI people understandably get very offended when you refer to the whole of the UK as "England".  It would be like referring to all Americans as "Texans".

Comment: On a deeper level, the history is:

Comment: Scotland and England: 

Scotland and England were both independent kingdoms, going right back to the late-first millennium, with separate kings, currencies, parliaments, etc.  England invaded Scotland several times, most seriously during 1296 and 1314, but were repelled each time by the Scots, who won a decisive victory at Bannockburn.  Much later, in the 17th/18th Century, a complicated mix of factors led to Scotland and England deciding to unify and create the modern United Kingdom, as a union of nations of equal status. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 it's important to realise that this Union was a very different thing from the much earlier attempts by England to invade Scotland and colonise it - it was (in theory) a genuine Union between two (and later more) countries of equal status, with the creation of a new nationality called "British", which designated people from either country.  In particular, Scotland was never colonised and is certainly NOT, and has never been, an English colony.  Scots are fiercely independent and patriotic and resent foreigners implicitly assuming that we are "just part of England".

Comment: Wales and NI have a more complicated history.  Unlike Scotland, Wales *was* conquered by England, and at the time of the Union with Scotland, was "part of England", but over time, the existence of the new constitutional framework of the United Kingdom allowed Wales to develop a status similar to Scotland and England, as a country which is a member of the United Kingdom.  This had been true for all practical purposes for a very long time, but was officially recognised in the 20th Century.

Comment: The history of Northern Ireland would take a book to explain, but the (very) abridged version is: 

England conquered Ireland in the medieval era, but (again, very simplistic) didn't really make a serious or sustained effort to seriously colonise Ireland until the reign of Elizabeth I and her successor, the Scottish-English King James VI and I.  In this era, the Anglo-Irish aristocracy were created in Ireland, and also working-class "planters" from Britain (mainly Scots, but not exclusively) went over to Ulster to establish communities.  1/2

Comment: 2/2 the descendants of the "Ulster-Scots" are the British-Northern Irish population today.  Of course, there remained some native Irish Catholic people in Ulster, although many of the Irish Catholic people in Ulster today are descended, not from original inhabitants, but from outsiders who have moved there over time.  

In the early-20th Century, the people of the rest of Ireland descended to revolt and secede from the Union, but a majority of the people of Ulster wanted to remain in the UK, so they seceded from Ireland and formed NI. (again, a VERY simplistic summary of a very complex time)

Answer (score 37):

English = of England
Great Britain = England + Scotland + Wales
British = of Great Britain (usually, but may also mean "of the United Kingdom")
United Kingdom = Great Britain + Northern Ireland

From the Wikipedia article [Terminology of the British Isles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminology_of_the_British_Isles), see images of the British Isles, the United Kingdom, Great Britain, and England respectively.

[image: The British Isles] [image: The United Kingdom] [image: Great Britain] [image: England]

See the Euler diagram for completeness (the blue ones are legal entities, and green ones are geographical).

[image: Euler diagram]

Comment: -1 Though informative, this answers the geographical question which the OP specifically and carefully **didn't** ask (*"What I am not asking: ..."*).

Comment: @Hugo: My disclaimer was to prevent people from solely answering in geographical terms. If, because there's no logically necessary connection (viz 'American'), it turned out (and it seems that way) that the ethnonyms and toponyms correspond, then a geographical explanation could help.

Comment: @Hugo: See Mitch's comment above, and also the first line of Affable Geek's answer. The OP just wanted to know the meanings of "English" and "British" without necessarily involving geography, but geography *is* an unavoidable part of the answer. As I said in the first three lines of the answer, "English" means "of England" and "British" means "of Great Britain", and these are precisely geographical terms; there's no way around it. Every single answer above invokes geography.

Comment: I’m trying to see how the three isles at the bottom fit in. Are the Manx British?

Comment: No - politically they are nothing to do with GB or UK. They do have the queen, but only for historic reasons that date to before there was a Britain

Comment: The situation in Mann is complex. The UK government is *able* to legislate over the island, but rarely does. (It last did in 1967.) Most Manx residents are either British citizens or British subjects. Manx passports are issued by the UK passport office, though are clearly marked "British Islands/Isle of Man". Passports issued to British citizens (not subjects) say "European Union" too. The UK government handles foreign relations and defence on Tynwald's behalf. Mann is in currency union with the UK. The appeals process in Mann's judicial system allows a final appeal to the UK's privy council.

Comment: I think you would be hard pressed to find any current usage of 'British' to be restricted to those from Great Britain in the geographical sense, i.e., excluding people from N. Ireland. Politically of course you can find people from N. Ireland who might claim only to be Irish, but this is a separate issue unrelated to geography. 'British' refers to "UK-ian" not "Great Britian-ian". Roughly it corresponds to who gets a standard British passport, which gives you "right to abode in the United Kingdom". So your third line should at the top should be reversed.

Comment: N. Ireland is complicated by the fact that all N. Irelanders are dual Irish and British citizens.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks! I think you're right. (Nice to see you on this site.) I'm in two minds about editing this answer I last touched almost ten years ago, and bumping up this question again. So I'll just leave this comment here acknowledging that yes, I think, "British" these days more often means "of the UK" than "of Great Britain". (Incidentally, [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=History_of_the_United_Kingdom&oldid=1014963246) says the name started to be shortened to "United Kingdom"/"UK" (rather than "Britain") more after 1945, but doesn't give a citation.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR No worries. It seems I was having an [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/386/) moment. :)

Answer (score 11):

Geography really is a piece of the equation here, sorry...

**Britain** (and thus the adjective *British*) refers geographically to the whole of the island on which England, Wales, and Scotland lie.  By extension, when the United Kingdom held onto the northern part of Ireland, they too were subjects of the *British* Empire.  (It was a British empire, where the English were the dominant partners of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland).

The **English** (descendants of the Angles who come originally from Saxony i.e. northern Germany) comprise the bulk of the island, including London (Shakespeare), Manchester (soccer hooligans!), Liverpool (the Beatles!), and the like.  (Cornwall is technically English, but just barely).  The English are also well known for their inedible cooking and bad dental hygene that renders said food capable of being passed through the mouth into the stomach without imparting taste.

> Please Note: I'm purposely having some fun here with the stereotypes, not because I believe them, but because I'm trying to add a hint of connotation and possibly humor to the narrative.

The **Welsh** (Cardiff and the site of every quarry made popular in Doctor Who) and the **Scots** (Edinborough, Glasglow, Loch Ness, and the only accents that Americans can truly make fun of) are "native" to the islands — think of them as Celtic or Gaelic or Picts (indigenous to the island, insofar as they were here before the Romans.) — and have the reputation of being a little bit 'hick' or 'redneck' as we say in the states when compared against the English.  Culturally, the English would be more "refined," in that they were the ones who conquered everyone else, and nothing says refined like having killed off and subjugated all your neighbors. As an aside, the Queen's son is currently the Prince of Wales — think of it as a consolation prize, and I think you'll get how the English perceive the Welsh.

To understand being British over against being English you have to realize that everybody on the island of Great Britain (again, the big island that ain't Ireland!) and those Englishmen who live in Northern Ireland are all subjects of the same queen — the ruler of the United Kingdom (hence the UK).  To be British is not to be European but distinctly part of the island.

Incidentally, [Dave Mitchell](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bOqY2xSD6U) does a pretty good job of it too...

Comment: Are you British?  I mean, would you know of any of the possible social implications the OP mentioned?

Comment: The Scots originally came from Ireland - what we call Scotland was originally inhabited by the Picts. They're as native as the Angles.

Comment: Surely there are English hicks in the English countryside, and Scottish sophisticates in Glasgow and Edinburgh.

Comment: *Britain* is also used as an abbreviation of the *United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland*, in addition to the big island of *Great Britain*. And *British* for residents of whichever area you're using.

Comment: In a logical world, *British* would mean "living on the island of Britain: ie English, Welsh or Scottish", *Irish* would mean 'living on the island of Ireland*, and there would be new words for 'citizen of the UK' (*Ukayer*?) and for 'citizen of the country formerly known as the Republic of Ireland'. Sadly, I don't see it happening any time soon.

Comment: "the site of every quarry made popular in Doctor Who" - it's only the new series that has been primarily shot in Wales, and that has tended to avoid quarries. Most of (old) Dr. Who's quarries were a short drive out of London.

Comment: @TimLymington. I've seen *Ukonian* suggested somewhere for "a citizen of the UK". Awkwardly, the Republic of Ireland is not an official name of the state. It's merely Ireland, which is also the name of the Island of which the state is the major constituent (sometimes called the Island of Ireland).

Comment: @TRiG; agreed, which is the difference between *formerly* and *formally*.  And personally, I would hate to be either a *Ukayer* or a *Ukonian*: I merely said it would be logical.

Comment: Are the capital and _Doctor Who_ the only recognisable feature of Wales? Tom Jones, people!

Comment: @DangerFourpence. The only part of Wales I know well is Holyhead. (I have climbed Snowdon twice, but I pass through Holyhead a lot.)

Comment: @DangerFourpence The main recognisable feature of Wales is, naturally, Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch.

Answer (score 11):

You need to invest the five minutes it takes to watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNu8XDBSn10) on YouTube.  It is a brilliant and thorough explanation of all of the terms relating to the geographical and political terms related to Britain, England, etc.

If somehow the YouTube link dies, you can see the entire script for this video on the [author's blog](http://www.cgpgrey.com/blog/the-difference-between-the-united-kingdom-great-britain-england).

There's a lot of information in this video, but the most important for purposes of OP's question is this:

> Unlike England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland, Great Britain is
>   a geographical term rather than a political term.

With respect to the OP's specific question, there are precise definitions of the places **England** and **Britain** and therefore precise definitions of their adjectives *English* and *British*.  However, with people using language imprecisely, as they do, there are lots of opportunities for confusion which could be interpreted as *nuance*, when in fact these subtle differences are errors in communication.

Comment: Thank you. This particular Englishman was unfamiliar with some of the details...

Answer (score 9):

No, “English” and
 “British” are never exact synonyms, and please don't use them that way.

The most important rule: only call someone English if you know they're English. If you call them English and they're Welsh, Scottish or Irish, it's not only incorrect, but for some is deeply insulting. This is in part due to the historical English oppression against the Welsh, Scottish and Irish that isn't easily forgotten.

The safest thing when you don't know is to call them British. Still, some Welsh, Scottish and Irish would rather not be associated with a term including England, but it's better than getting it wrong and insulting them with "English".

In a similar vein, only use England as a generic country name when you know you specifically only mean England. Otherwise you're excluding a lot of people and places. If you're talking about English pirates, do you mean to exclude the Welsh Captain Morgan? If it's English engineers of the industrial revolution, what about the Scottish James Watt? English punk: so no Northern Ireland's Stiff Little Fingers and The Undertones? Use the UK or [Great] Britain if that's what you really mean.

Comment: Note that there are people resident in England who prefer to be identified as British. This was certainly an attitude among some of the Afro-Carribbean community at one time, when it was for some reason an issue aired in the mass media.

Answer (score 6):

The preferred option really varies on a person's political standpoint and sense of national identity.  I would say that typically Welsh or Scottish people would prefer to be referred to as such rather than as British due to the strength of their nation's culture.  In England this is likely to be more dilute, resulting in a greater acceptance of the British identity.  Having said that, I would say that I am English rather than British! I certainly agree that the potential for a social faux pas is high and I personally would always side with the smaller geographical unit of English, Welsh or Scottish rather than British.

Then again it must also be noted that citizenship and nationality is exclusively British. Officially nationality of anyone born in the UK is British and it would be incorrect to be referred to as an "English Citizen".

Regarding people from Northern Ireland, I would consider Irish as referring to citizens of the Republic of Ireland (geographically southern and central Ireland).

Unfortunately, I am doubtful that there is a definitive answer as to which is appropriate as it will depend almost entirely on the personal views on the reader.

Comment: Forgive my obtuseness, but what is your (sub) nationality (given the 'having said that')?

Comment: @Mitch: Rory says he's English, and identifies more with being English than British.

Comment: @Hugo: becauseof my lack of understanding of the range of he meanings of British and English (that is what the question is about), and his reference to Welsh or Scottish being referred to one or the other, I took his statement to somehow imply that he might actually 'be' Scottish or Welsh. So I'm looking for full explanation with full disclosure.

Comment: @Mitch sorry for any confusion, I am indeed English (in the sense of being from England).  I only mention the Welsh and Scottish (Scotts in particular) as they are perhaps overall more likely to take offence if referred to as British due to their more concentrated national identity.  It could be perhaps said that a person from England is more likely to use the terms interchangeably without thinking about it leading to it being very hard to make a distinction between the two even for someone who is living in the country.

Comment: Regarding Irishness, the term "Irish" is used here in Ireland for all people who live on the island, although Unionists from Northern Ireland may often choose to identify themselves as "British" in the ethnic sense.

Answer (score 5):

For people not from Britain and Ireland, the safest way through the minefield is to initially use the term "British" for someone who is English, Welsh or Scottish. They may correct you, but you probably won't cause offence. If they're from either the Republic of Ireland or Northern Ireland, use the term "Irish". There is an outside chance that a Unionist from Northern Ireland may slightly baulk at the term, but in this case they'll just correct you. If you're not sure if someone is British or Irish, just ask (especially if there's a possibility of them being Irish).

People from these islands have a whole load of other historical baggage to take into consideration but this shouldn't spoil it for everyone else IMO :)

Comment: Unionists would historically have regarded themselves as Irish, were less likely to do so at the hight of the Troubles, and may be more happy with that designation again today.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some great answers to this. Hugo explained it well, when he wrote "**No, “English” and “British” are never exact synonyms, and please don't use them that way.**" That's true.

Affable Geek alluded to an important point, when they wrote "**(Cornwall is technically English, but just barely).**" Technically English in that this is a status that has historically been imposed on it, by England. Many Cornish people in the past and today, have considered themselves as Cornish and not English. They are Celtic, with a history and language (even though they speak English, as well) that are not of England. Therefore, not English in the true sense of the word.

Basically, English is just for those things that are of England only. Including the language, even though it is used in other parts of the world, it is only of England. British, is for things that are of the entire United Kingdom, generally. So, British includes English things and others.

> As an American, I naively think of British and English as exact
>   synonyms. I know I'm wrong, but I just don't know in what way. I am
>   vaguely aware that people in the UK hold strong opinions about one or
>   the other term and how it is applied, and using one instead of the
>   other has dire social implications. So there is geography (Britain vs.
>   England), but more importantly the adjectives British and English, and
>   those adjectives each one by themselves, may mean different things in
>   different contexts, and depending on the speaker and the listener. Can
>   anyone explain the nuances of the differences as used by those who
>   might consider themselves English (or British, if that's an acceptable
>   usage)? How about by the non-English/non-British (again if it's
>   appropriate to use such terms).

I'm British. I know that this question is an issue for a lot of people in the world. It can be explained simply.

Most people are familiar with the words England and English but, are not as familiar with the other words, like United Kingdom, Britain, British, Scottish, Welsh, Northern Irish or Cornish. Therefore, they assume that England and English apply to everything of the UK. It is an assumption based on a lack of information.

A simple way to understand it, is to compare the UK to the USA. The USA is a country made up of states. Each state, with a different name. People can be New Yorkers or Californians and they are Americans. However, not all Americans are New Yorkers or Californians.

For the UK, replace the word states, with the words "home nations". Then, replace the state names with the names Scotland, Wales, England, Cornwall, Northern Ireland. Scottish, Welsh, English, Northern Irish and Cornish are the words for describing things that are of each of these home nations. People can be English and they are British. However, not all British people are English.

I know that the UK and the USA are not entirely comparable but, for the purposes of this subject, the comparison is a suitable one.

There is one other point that is worth making, in regards to this subject.

The word British, does not only mean things or people that are of the UK. It also applies to the things or people that are of the overseas territories of the UK. Whether colonies, dependencies or anything else; these are territories that belong to but are not part of, the UK.

These include examples such as the Falkland Islands and Gibraltar. Even the Isle of Man, which is close to the UK but, still not part of it. These are all British overseas territories and their peoples are British citizens.

Comment: This is confusing. At first you say "As an American, I ..." then you say "I'm British". And also you gave two separate answers, for neither of which is it clear where the 'answer' is. Can you clarify, and emphasize what the answer is supposed to be (and if appropriate, combine (or maybe there really are two separate coherent answers)).

Comment: Yes, I gave two answers, Mitch. In the first, my points were that many foreigners (non-British people) are not familiar with the other parts of the UK (Scotland, Wales, Cornwall and Northern Ireland), so they assume that the entire country is England and everything of it, is English. Also, it is a situation like that of the USA. New Yorkers are Americans but, not all Americans are New Yorkers. In this case, English is equivalent to New Yorkers and British to Americans.

Comment: My other points were, that Cornwall is like Scotland and Wales. It is not genuinely English but, unlike Scotland and Wales, it has had English status imposed on it, by England. Also, that English describes things that are of just one part of the UK (England), but British describes things that are of the UK in general.

Comment: @Tristan: I think you could safely put both of your entries together, because they are both part of the same answer, and will get the same assessment as separately and with respect to those answers already given.

Comment: To suggest that Cornwall is similar to Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland is tosh. Cornwall has always been part of England right back to Saxon times. What rubbish.

Comment: How then do you explain its distinctive, Celtic identity that includes a Celtic language that is related to the other, Celtic languages but not, to English which is Germanic and not even Celtic?

Answer (score 2):

It's confusing but easy enough to understand that Scots, Welsh, English and Northern Irish all fall under United Kingdom citizenship, or they are called "British subjects". Some people can never seem to get it into their heads that British is not synonymous with English.

To be fair, it is confusing because Scotland, Wales, English and Northern Ireland are considered separate countries but all share the same passport and then the whole Great Britain vs. UK thing makes it even more confusing because British subject status refers to the entire United Kingdoms which is short for the United Kingdom of Great Britain AND Northern Ireland. So technically GB is English, Scotland, Wales; but with Northern Ireland they make the UK. Most Irish people just call themselves Irish so we might assume they are from the Republic of Ireland.

Comment: None of the four are actually 'separate countries.' Wales is a principality, Northern Ireland is a province and Scotland is - under discussion.

Comment: @TimLymington Wales is not a principality, nor has it been for nearly 500 years.

Comment: @Gareth: " Wales: A principality of the United Kingdom west of England on the island of Great Britain. Incorporated with England since the Act of Union." (The Free Dictionary). Rhetoric doesn't change the facts: a word means what it is used to mean.

Comment: @TimLymington Repeating an incorrect assertion does not make it any more correct. Some reading for you: [The Principality of Wales ... existed between 1216 and 1536...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Wales) [Wales was a principality, once upon a time. But that was in 1542. 472 years ago… 472 years.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/wales/posts/No-Wales-isnt-a-principality-sorry) [We were alerted by the Welsh Government to the fact that the notion of Wales as a principality is now outdated...](http://www.cymru.uk.com/wales-is-no-longer-a-principality-its-a-country/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a risk that questions like this get bogged down in the pedantry of states and laws, and don't answer in a broad enough way that someone might surefootedly use the terminology and understand what is meant by what is said.

I see that in the other answers, so want to respond here, despite this question already having many answers.

The modern settlement is increasingly a group of disparate nations (England, Scotland, Wales, etc), each with distinct, but closely related, cultural, historical, familial, etc, ties. They live within a single state (UK, Britain, etc). I imagine that the situation is somewhat analogous to first nations settlements some in other countries (but not of course a strong historical analogy, this is just a menmonic).

While there are subtle and important distinctions within these terms, very few people know them, even those who embody them. The crucial distinction is someone who wants to be identified with the culture, music, traditions, etc, of their nation (a Scotsman, Englishman, Welshwoman, Cornishwoman, etc); and someone who wishes to emphasize the unity of the whole state and its political institutions (and maybe they believe that the cultural distinctions are minor), they are British.

So someone in Scotland might want you to call them Scottish *or* British, (but not the other), and so on. It's their choice.

In practice, I believe you're less likely to get pulled up for calling someone English, Welsh, Scottish, etc, than calling them British, just by numbers. But we all are burnt, even us natives: you just have to roll with it, and remember, :-) .

The English are in the privileged position of having been considered the senior partner historically, and so tend not to see what the fuss is about, as they can go about their business largely ignoring the other nations, and so are prone to mixing and matching and so confusing foreigners. That is *much, much* less likely of someone who's Scottish or Welsh.

Answer (score 2):

I am English, from England.

British, means 'from Britain' which is composed of England, Scotland, or Wales. These were originally three separate countries, which are in a kind of alliance. People from these countries still think of each one as being a country, even though to you, they may appear to be like 'regions'.

English means - from England - that country of Britain.
Scottish means - from Scotland - that northern country of Britain.
Welsh means - from Wales - that Western country of Britain

British means - from any of those 3 countries.

English means - from England.

If you ask me 'are you British'? I might reply 'yes, I am English'. Because, as I say, we think of ourselves as coming from our individual country - ie England, Scotland or Wales.

So I am going to tell you my country, when you ask.

Being called 'British' is really only for passport application or immigration.

If you call me 'a brit' or talk about 'the brits' I might also get offended - that sounds a bit rude to my ears.

If you accidentally call a Scottish person 'English', or a Welsh person, 'English' they may get offended. They will bellow 'noooo I'm Scot!' Or lilt 'no, I'm from Wales!'.

You probably won't go the other way and ask an English person if they are Welsh or Scottish - due to the English language being so popular that makes people think that Britain IS English or is - England.

But it's not, it's Scotland and Wales as well.

I've left out beautiful green, friendly Ireland because its a bit complicated to explain and has changed also.

The reason why people may get offended if you wrongly name their country is - boundary issues, changes in which country is part of what, individual identity, and history. And discussions about 'who should be a part of what' tend to be ongoing... and contentious.

England, having the governmental control over Britain, is sometimes resented by people from Scotland and Wales, who now have their own parliaments too, and there are people in those countries who want devolution and independence from England.

This is why, if you ask an English person if they are Welsh or Scottish, they may not mind. But the other way round - they may.

It's treading on the toes of history...

PS Cornwall, that long toe of England heading South West, is really a country too, a beautiful one, inhabited by the Corns. They may also baulk at being called 'English'. They are 'Cornish'.

Lastly, I suggest you ask: Are you from around the UK? And then ask 'where from?' That will probably be fairly safe!

Answer (score 1):

I thought to refer to a book that expounds the legal difference. See Neil Guthrie [DPhil English (Oxon), LLB (Toronto)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/guthrieneil/)'s   [*Guthrie’s Guide to Better Legal Writing*  (2017)](https://www.amazon.ca/Guthries-Guide-Better-Legal-Writing/dp/1552214729). p. 95.

[image]