# Adjectival "Anglican" for "English", and "Anglicanism" for "Anglomania" in AmE

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage, formality

Harrap's New Shorter French and English Dictionary, Ed. 1985 [[Harrap's Shorter French Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrap%27s_Shorter_French_Dictionary)], points up adjectival "Anglican" as an Americanism for "English," and "Anglicanism" as an AmE equivalent for "Anglomania," i.e. an excessive respect for English customs, etc. [source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Anglomania?s=t)

Though RH, MW, WNW, and the AED all validate the sense "English" of adjectival "Anglican" [of or pertaining to England, its inhabitants, or the English language] [source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Anglican) [source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anglican) [source](http://www.yourdictionary.com/anglican) [source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anglican), I can't seem to find a US dictionary online to state the sense "Anglomania" of "Anglicanism" as fact.

Does adjectival "Anglican" actually have (or once had) currency in AmE to refer to what pertains to, or is characteristic of England, or its inhabitants, its institutions, etc.?

Also, is any one of you familiar with "Anglicanism" used—apparently by analogy with Americanism (3rd sense [source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/americanism))—as another term for "Anglomania"?

Even though I couldn't find any sourced evidence of the latter, I got to find "Anglicanism" used—by analogy with the most common meaning of "Americanism"—for "Anglicism,"or as a broad equivalent to "Briticism."

E.g.

> "Boffin" is an Anglicanism for researcher. [source](http://geektable.activeboard.com/t49870324/i-was-just-trying-to-control-my-blood-pressure-honest/)
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boffin

Yes, I know, we Colonialists mispronounce "scone', but the OED gives Anglican pronunciation. [source](http://wordcraft.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/790109806/m/126108655/p/3)

> Though staying true to the 20th-century Anglican idiom -- some Britten and even more Vaughan Williams (though quite a bit of French... [source](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2000-12-03/news/0012030016_1_organ-silent-night-carol)

If you insist upon using the archaic word *vampir*, I would appreciate if you would use the Anglican pronunciation -- "vampire"... [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=98pE_4DUccsC&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=%22anglican+pronunciation%22&source=bl&ots=WKLKSpKqBP&sig=UvV9AQFAg7bF5uqsh2nYu5IMfLE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=mbc1U4bLAomc0wXtmoCoBg&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=%22anglican%20pronunciation%22&f=false)

> Kevin doesn't mind this, and in fact he usually introduces himself to others using this Anglican pronunciation... [source](http://www.delaguila.info/Website/HomeFAQs.htm)

"It's not our problem, lieutenant," he said, choosing the more Anglican pronunciation. [Starsky & Hutch]  [source](https://www.squidge.org/flamingo/starskyhutchslash/classic/Dargelos/twostep.htm)

> And the thick Anglican accent when he did answer "that would be nice unless you wanted to finish off what you brother started." [source](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/7442514/1/Nephilim-The-Hunter-s-Moon)

To any whom speak colloquial Anglican/American... [source](http://www.blind-guardian.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=36631&start=50)

> At least Russell Crowe was attempting a Northern vernacular, and can be forgiven for at least *trying* to incorporate Anglican colloquialisms... [Movies Stack Exchange 2014] [source](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17615/where-is-jerome-supposed-to-be-from)

It is an effortless read, barring the few Anglican colloquialisms that creep into every now and then. [Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone reviews] [source](http://www.epinions.com/review/j-k-rowling-harry-potter-and-the-sorcerer-s-stone/book-review-5536-A35EC7E-38696D08-prod2)

> Dog farts. Ugh. We have a Staffordshire-Rat Terrier mix. These breeds are known as "fiests", which turns out to be an Old Anglican slang for fart. [source](http://aa.activeboard.com/mobile.spark?p=topic&topic=32212844)

lummox: A clumsy, stupid person (1825 Anglican slang, root "lummock"... [source](http://www.girlsaskguys.com/life/q544786-what-your-new-word-of-day)

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lummox

Comment: Nobody uses *Anglican* to mean *English*.

Comment: @tchrist So why is it pointed up as such in three reliable sources online? That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @tchrist Not three, but four authoritative online dictionaries corroborate that definition http://www.yourdictionary.com/anglican

Comment: Sounds like the three dictionaries are wrong then.  Anglican is a Church, and not even an exclusively English one.  Never heard of it used in any other sense.

Comment: What tchrist and Oldcat said. It's all well and good that three reliable sources online say something, but good luck finding any Americans who will admit to using Anglican to mean English.

Comment: @Oldcat How can not three, but FOUR authoritative dictionaries possibly be wrong? Come on, gimme a break, Oldcat! :-)

Comment: Look, if you want to ask native speakers a question, you might as well accept their answers that it is as commonly seen as Hen's Teeth.  Actually less rare, as I have seen Hen's Teeth before. Perhaps they are all copying each other.

Comment: OED says ***anglomania** is *"probably after French **anglomanie**"*. Given that [***Anglomaniac** has been almost totally supplanted by **Anglophile***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Anglomaniac%2CAnglophile&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAnglomaniac%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAnglophile%3B%2Cc0), I would avoid it anyway. And *Anglican = English* has no significant currency except in the "organised religion" context.

Comment: I guess there are two schools of thought on what constitutes a language. One school of thought would hold that an academy rigorously defines and controls a language and the language is what the academy puts into a book. Another school of thought would hold that a language is defined by how people use it to communicate. Neither school is right or wrong, but they are different, and different places favor different schools. As a member of the latter school, I hesitate to call using Anglican for English *wrong* - if its meaning is clear in context, how can it be *wrong*? - but this is uncommon.

Comment: @Patrick87: I don't begin to understand why, but this OP has a particular tendency to present (perforce, *scant*) evidence supporting non-standard usages, and try to get ELU users to agree such usages are "acceptable".

Comment: OED **Anglican** - *In non-religious contexts: English. Now **rare**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Gimme a break, Fumble! :-) None of these dictionaries point up adjectival "Anglican" for "English" as nonstandard. On top of that, this sense comes in the first place in Webster's New World Dictionary http://www.yourdictionary.com/anglican. The fact it's unfamiliar to you and to some AmE native speakers doesn't mean necessarily that this sense to "Anglican" is not (or was not once) in common use in some parts of the US. The United States is a vast country, you know. :-)

Comment: @Nourished: You consistently miss the point that users such as myself and tchrist are *highly competent native speakers with wide knowledge of English*. Questions about "prevalence" are obviously somewhat subjective, but the chances of there being any significant regional, historical, or contextual usage that either is or was "common" are vanishingly small, regardless of whether some dictionaries choose to include this sense. As implied by my OED citation, you are more likely to look favourably on the usage simply because it chimes with current *French* words.

Comment: @Patrick87 - There might be two views, but since there is no Academy in BrE or AmE, that school needs to not assume the top down model has force in English.

Comment: @Oldcat Oh, I completely agree; my point is that a bunch of dictionaries the English language do not (necessarily) make.

Comment: I would suggest that *East Anglican* is a misprint (or misunderstanding) for *East Anglian* which is "of or pertaining to East Anglia" -- the big bulge on the east side of England.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I never denied the fact that you both actually were highly native speakers with wide knowledge of English. That said, I think you really should eat humble pie, Fumble, and accept that some native speakers of AmE might use (or once might have used) adjectival "Anglican" to refer to what id characteristic of England, as opposed to "their English", and that maybe it was standard AmE usage back in the old days, and might still be in current use in that sense in some parts of the US.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for pointing out, Andrew. :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Imagine just one second that some other highly respected, competent English native speaker with wide knowledge of English like you reacts tomorrow or in a month to the accepted answer to this OP and say "Wait, in my neck of the wood, "Anglican" is commonly used to refer to what is characteristic of England, I have oftentimes heard it used in that way". What would you say to that?

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Keep in mind that most dictionaries of English (especially the OED) are descriptive and not prescriptive; if someone, somewhere in a widely-read written work has used the word that way, the OED will record it. That doesn't mean that most modern readers, encountering that usage (`Anglican` meaning "English), wouldn't confuse it with `Anglican` for "member of the Anglican Church."

Comment: @NourishedGourmet - I would then say that the OED is wrong, and the usage isn't rare.

Comment: @outisnihil I can't seem to find any fault in that. Just time will tell [as far as the OP goes]. :-)

Comment: @Oldcat LOL Does the OED support either "reception room" or "reception"as synonymous to "vestibule", i.e. the small room, generally 10 ft. x 10 ft., usually found at the entrance of office buildings, Oldcat? ;-)

Comment: Whatever the multiple dictionaries say, they don't give an idea what people actually use. At least to an American, you will sound very, very strange if you use 'Anglican' instead of 'English'.

Comment: Never heard these in the Midwest or California. We use *English* and *Anglophile.* And I agree with FF that the OP really needs to develop a better screening process for judging whether these questions are even plausible. It's easy to cherry pick long lists of bizarre usages on the internet. NG, try using Google Ngrams instead of Search to get a better feel for real usage frequencies.

Comment: Also, please consolidate your edits! Excessive editing is disruptive and leads to posts becoming community wiki like this.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Using Google Ngrams to compare "Anglican" with "English"? Come on, Brad, you gotta be kidding! You know pretty well it's not fair game ASA the result is quite predictable. My impression is that some people in AmE might use (or might have used) "Anglican" to refer to what is characteristic of England, as opposed to what is characteristic of the US, by analogy with Latin American native speakers of Spanish who typically refer to what pertains to, or is characteristic of Spain, its inhabitants, its culture, etc., as "Castilian", as opposed to their own Spanish.

Comment: @BraddSzonye And so, I wouldn't be surprised that some people in the US when asked what the language spoken in England might reply "Anglican" or "Anglican English", just like they would respond "Australian English", "South African English", "Canadian English", "Scottish (or Scotch) English" for respectively English as spoken in Australia, South Africa, Canada, and Scotland, as opposed to English as spoken in the US.

Comment: NG: The more I read your examples the more they sound like malapropisms or, more bluntly, mistakes. For each example there is a perfectly good much more common term, namely 'British'. So, you got us, some Americans use 'Anglican'. We're all telling you that when they do, everyone else cringes. So if you want to pass the 'spy test' don't use 'Anglican'.

Comment: @Mitch If you posted that as an answer, I'd up vote it.

Comment: @Mitch unless a word, idiom, pronunciation, or an accent is typical of an English dialect associated with the UK, it sounds to me more accurate to say it's an Anglicanism than a Briticism to some extent. Besides, most of my examples are related to the English as spoken in England: "boffin" was first recorded in a novel by Charles Dickens, "lummox" roots from the Midlands, "feist" from Old English, Harry Potter is English and most of the settings take place in England, etc. ;-)

Comment: @NourishedGourmet I have a pretty wide acquaintance of Americans in the northeast and midwest, and I have never heard an American speaker use `Anglican` to mean `English` rather than "member of CoE or Episcopalian Church."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever the multiple dictionaries say, they don't give an idea what people actually use.

At least to an American, you will sound very, very strange if you use 'Anglican' instead of 'English'. It may have once been a synonym for 'English' but isn't anymore.

There is some subtlety here, because the overwhelmingly preferred term for that Christian sect is called 'Episcopalian' in the US. The word 'Anglican' (for that church) is recognized but not the preferred use. But there is no subtlety to the fact that in whatever context 'Anglican' is presented, it always refers specifically to the religion, not to general English things.

Going through your examples one by one, to a native speaker they sound like malapropisms or, more bluntly, mistakes. For each example there is a perfectly good much more common term, namely 'British'.

So, yes, some Americans use 'Anglican' for English or British ([see this question for further distinction between those two](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51978/what-is-the-difference-between-english-and-british)). We're all telling you that when 
they do, everyone else cringes. So if you want to pass the 'spy test' don't use 'Anglican'

Comment: You might want to consider this link, Mitch http://archive.thetablet.co.uk/article/16th-november-1912/30/definitions

Comment: NG: I think that letter proves my point more than yours. That letter was published in 1912 in a Catholic (religious) journal. So the letter was using 'Anglican' to mean English in the religious sense, namely the Curch of England, not generally English.

Comment: To my perspective, that letter proves on the contrary that the term "Anglican" to refer to a thing characteristic of England as opposed to the rest of the English speaking world was seemingly not, back in the old days, as uncommon as one might think, and still might be in currency in some parts of the US. Look, it's relatively in common use on my side of the pond to refer to what pertains to, or is characteristic of Germany as "Teutonic" e.g. Teutonic art, or what roots from Portugal as "Lusitanian". Sure enough such adjectival terms compared with respectively "German" and "Portuguese".

Comment: That quote, sourced from Movies StackExchange, is from a 28 year old American: "At least Russell Crowe was attempting a Northern vernacular, and can be forgiven for at least *trying* to incorporate Anglican colloquialisms' http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17615/where-is-jerome-supposed-to-be-from

Answer (score 7):

It's probably best to use English instead of Anglican (and Anglomania instead of Anglicanism), as [Anglican](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicanism) is used to describe the Church of England, while "English" does not have this confusion.

Dictionary.com reflects this in its meaning for "[Anglican](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anglican)":

**adjective**

1.
of or pertaining to the Church of England.

2.
related in origin to and in communion with the Church of England, as various Episcopal churches in other parts of the world.

3.
English (  def 1 ) .

**noun**

4.
a member of the Church of England or of a church in communion with it.

5.
a person who upholds the system or teachings of the Church of England.

Comment: I'm nowhere near unfamiliar with "Anglican" used nominally and adjectivally to a member of the Church of England, ASA it has the same meaning in France. However, "Anglican" used adjectivally as a synonym for "English" sounds unnatural to my ear, and so I wish someone could tell if it has or once had currency in AmE in such sense, and also could explain what the story is to it.

Comment: To my American (NE) ear, Anglican means a member of the Church of England, or of a more conservative Episcopalian church. That said, one might find examples of Anglican for "English" in American speech that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 6):

OED does note that *Anglican* has been used to mean *English*:

> **2.** *gen.* In non-religious contexts: English. Now *rare.*
>
> > 1871   J. Ruskin *Fors Clavigera* I. iii. 19   The quite Anglican character of [King] Richard, to his death.
> > 1959   *Amer. Lit.* **30** 449   The sources of future enrichings of the Anglican speech are the same old fountains.

Sense **1** is the “Church of England; Episcopalian” sense which Ronan has explained.

The two citations I reproduce are the latest OED has. Both are literary, and the last is (a) American — the English would not have used *Anglican* to mean *English* by the 1950s — and (b) very literary. In fact, out of context, the entire sentence is obscure.

I conclude that *Anglican* **has been** used to mean *English,* but is no longer.

A better word for *Anglicanism* nowadays might be *Anglicism.*

> **1. a.**  A characteristically English word, phrase, or idiom, esp. one introduced into a sentence in another language.

OED has citations for that word and use from the 1640s to after 2000.

Answer (score 2):

No one seems to have mentioned the prefix **'Anglo'**.

**'Anglo'** is widely used. Some people are 'Anglo-Jewish', 'Anglo-Italian', Anglo-Indian' etc. We talk of an 'Anglo-Japanese venture', and of 'Anglo-dominated business practices'. The English speaking world is sometimes referred to as 'The Anglosphere'.

Whilst 'Anglican' is nowadays mostly confined to religion, **'Anglo'** is alive and well as a prefix meaning 'English'.

This fact is confirmed by the OED.

Comment: The thing is the prefix "Anglo" is fairly common and easily perceivable by most people to not be confused with what is characteristic of the Amglican Church. This apparently is not the case for "Anglican". In one or two of my last examples, the sense to "Anglican" is actually borderline equivocal whether it is the religious or nonreligious meaning that is conveyed. :-)

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Do you similarly rule out, as being irrelevant to this discussion, words like 'Anglicise', Anglicism etc. which clearly are used by many Americans to refer to what is English? I am rather losing track of the motion under debate here. Is it entirely about the word 'Anglican' , used in a non-religious context?  May I also ask if there is any reason why it is so important to you to establish that there might be some little corner of America where 'Anglican'is still used to mean 'English'?